# How to return a GDI::Bitmap from a function

Tags: c++, bitmap, gdi+

How can I return a bitmap from a function?
This code doesn't work: Compiler error

```
 Gdiplus::Bitmap create()
 {
       Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(10,10,PixelFormat32bppRGB);

       // fill image
       return bitmap;
 }
```

I don't want to return a pointer as then it generate a chance for memory leak. (or if there is way to avoid this chance of memory leak)

Comment: The Bitmap class has a private copy constructor to prevent you from making copies.  Intentionally, copies of bitmaps take entirely too much memory.  You really do need to return a pointer.  Clearly that cannot be a pointer to a local variable, using *new* is required.

Comment: @Hans: Actually, `Gdiplus::Bitmap` really ought to have a move constructor, which would make the above code both valid and (because it is already just a wrapper for a handle value) optimal.  Hopefully these wrappers get a C++11 update soon.

Answer (score 3):

When you return an object from a function, the compiler needs to generate code to either copy or (in C++11) move that object.

`Gdiplus::Bitmap` does not have an accessible copy constructor (and predates C++11, so no moving either) so you're not allowed to do this. Depending on how you're using it, you might consider using something like an `std::unique_ptr` or possibly an `std::shared_ptr` instead.

Alternatively, you might want to create the `Bitmap` in the parent, and simply pass a pointer or reference to it to have your function fill it in as needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you were wanting code.  This is how you would pass the pointer back.

```
Gdiplus::Bitmap* create()
{
    Gdiplus::Bitmap* bitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(10,10,PixelFormat32bppRGB);

    // fill image
    return bitmap;
}
```

### Would this not work?

```
void create(Gdiplus::Bitmap& bitmap)
{
    bitmap = *(new Gdiplus::Bitmap(10,10,PixelFormat32bppRGB));
}
```

Where the context would be something like

```
int main()
{
    Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap; //ONLY WORKS IF IT HAS DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR
    create(bitmap);
}
```

I'm not familiar with Gdiplus, so if there is no default constructor then that wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks. The problem with this code is that if caller forgot to delete bitmap, then we have a memory leak.

Comment: This is true.  I guess it depends on who you are writing this for.  If you trust the programmer, then that is good.  If you don't, then use smart pointers!  As mentioned by Jerry Coffin