# GDI+ Bitmap Issues

Tags: c++, bitmap, gdi+, header-files

I'm having some issues using GDI plus in c++ for a project. I'm currently just trying to create a blank Bitmap in order to draw to it a later time, but I'm having some issues. My current code is this:

```
reptileRect.Height = windowHeight / 9;
reptileRect.Width = windowWidth / 15;
reptileRect.Y = (windowHeight - (windowHeight / 4));
reptileRect.X = windowWidth * ratio;



Bitmap bmp = Bitmap((INT)(reptileRect.Width * 2), (INT)(reptileRect.Width * 2));
```

But I'm getting an error to the effect of:

```
"Gdiplus::Bitmap::Bitmap(const Gdiplus::Bitmap &)" (declared at line 638 of "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\gdiplusheaders.h") is inaccessible
```

and `'Gdiplus::Bitmap::Bitmap': cannot access private member declared in class 'Gdiplus::Bitmap'`

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Wow, okay, I swear I'm usually not this stupid, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The Bitmap copy constructor is private to prevent copying of the Bitmap class (See related thread [How to return a GDI::Bitmap from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570133/how-to-return-a-gdibitmap-from-a-function?rq=1)). I guess you should try to initialise bmp directly

```
Bitmap bmp((INT)(reptileRect.Width * 2), (INT)(reptileRect.Width * 2));
```